# Disable Android Secondary Progress Bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

Is there away to make the secondary progress bar not show? My app needs a progress bar and it works fine, except the user can slide the bar and it shows a secondary progress bar which makes no sense in my app and looks confusing to the user. This is really a cosmetic issue for me, but I can't seem to disable it.  I need only the primary one to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

`<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
<clip><shape></shape></clip>
</item>`

Android requires to have this value defined but by using an empty shape you are providing a valid value that will never be displyed. I've used it in my project, it works fine for me.

Hope it will help you.